# How to use SWCollaborationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cloudkit, collaboration

[SWCollaborationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sharedwithyou/swcollaborationview) was introduced as a standard UI element to manage real-time collaboration between users in iOS16+. This is explained in this [Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sharedwithyou/adding_shared_content_collaboration_to_your_app). Similarly to [UICloudSharingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller), it's way to view participants to a share and manage sharing.

**Given that UICloudSharingController is broken in iOS16+ (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73888519/uicloudsharingcontroller-does-not-work-for-core-data-with-cloudkit)), how can I use SWCollaborationView in SwiftUI?**

My failed attempts so far:

The the WWDC22 talk introducing SWCollaborationView, the speaker embedded SWCollaborationView in UIBarButtonItem(customView:). I was not able to embed UIBarButtonItem(customView:) into my SwiftUI lifecycle app, because UIBarButtonItem does not conform to UIView and therefore cannot be introduced using UIViewRepresentable.

I also tried wrapping SWCollaborationView in UIViewRepresentable and introducing it directly. The result was identical to [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718404). When I wrapped it in ToolbarItem, the icon appeared but no action happened on tap. When I wrapped it in ToolbarItem and Button that would open an identical collaboration view as a popover, the icon appeared ([screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Kcv.jpg)) and on tap opened a popover where the same icon would appear ([screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLbXp.jpg). Only a second tap would correctly open the desired popover inherent to SWCollaborationView ([screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3suY7.jpg)). The code for this is below.

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit
import SharedWithYou

struct DetailView: View {
  var photo: Photo // some object saved in CloudKit, in this example a photo
  @State var showPopover = false
  @Binding var activeCover: ActiveCover? // for dismissal (not relevant for SWCollaborationView)

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("Some content of detail view")
      }
      .toolbar {
        if let existingShare = PersistenceController.shared.existingShare(photo: photo) {  // get the existing CKShare for this object (in this case we use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.fetchShares, but that's not really relevant)
          ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
            Button(action: {
              showPopover.toggle()
            }){
              CollaborationView(existingShare: existingShare) // <- icon appears, but without the number of participants
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
              CollaborationView(existingShare: existingShare) // <- icon appears AGAIN, with the number of participants. Instead, we want a popover inherent to SWCollabroationView!
            }
          }
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
          Button("Dismiss") { activeCover = nil }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct CollaborationView: UIViewRepresentable {
  let existingShare: CKShare

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SWCollaborationView {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
    itemProvider.registerCKShare(existingShare,
                                 container: PersistenceController.shared.cloudKitContainer,
                                 allowedSharingOptions: .standard)
    let collaborationView = SWCollaborationView(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    collaborationView.activeParticipantCount = existingShare.participants.count
    return collaborationView
  }
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: SWCollaborationView, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a TSI about this; Apple confirmed that SWCollaborationView is not compatible with SwiftUI at the moment and we should submit feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUi it's called [ShareLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sharelink)

Comment: I don't think so.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but ShareLink is the SwiftUI equivalent of UIActivityViewController. It can distribute a link to a CKShare, but it cannot show a list of current participants. It also lacks the ability to remove participants or stop sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but putting some .frame to CollaborationView makes it tappable.

```
CollaborationView(existingShare: existingShare).frame(width: 40, height: 40)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).